# Equally split the aligned items in tasks package

Tags: tasks

### Problem

I am now updating my resume and I found `tasks` package is a good choice to list my research interests in the same line (which could save a lot of space). Even though I basically got what I want, it seems that three items I list did not have same horizontal space and this makes it a little unsatisfactory.

[image]

### What I Have Done

I checked the [doc](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks_en.pdf) of the `tasks` package and especially the figure shown below, but it seems that we could not restrict the text width of each bullet point.
[image]

Did I miss something? Any input is appreciated.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
% EDIT
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{item-indent=3em, label-offset=0em, column-sep=2em}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](3)
\task Gaussian process machine learning \task Statistical learning theory  \task (Non)-convex optimization
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot I tried tabular when I didn't know `tasks` package exist, but I find it pretty ugly.

Comment: @marmot Sorry for the confusion, the code is just taken from my resume and I forgot to add margin setting. Already added it.

Comment: Thanks for your MWE! Do you want something like `\hspace{1em}\textbullet~~Gaussian process machine learning\hfill
\textbullet~~Statistical learning theory\hfill
\textbullet~~(Non)-convex optimization\hspace{1em}\par` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want :-).

Comment: You're welcome! (Please let me know if you think I should write an official answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tasks *are* equal width, but `Gaussian process machine learning` is too wide and there's no feasible line break point. Indeed you get a warning about

```latex
Overfull \hbox (11.3392pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 34--34
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Gaussian pro-cess ma-chine learning|
```

Fix: use `\raggedright`. In the code below, the first part sets rules to visually check the spacing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% EDIT
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
  item-indent=3em,
  label-offset=0em,
  column-sep=2em,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
\smash{\vrule height 0pt depth 10cm}%
\leaders\hrule\hfill
\smash{\vrule height 0pt depth 10cm}%
\leaders\hrule\hfill
\smash{\vrule height 0pt depth 10cm}%
\leaders\hrule\hfill
\smash{\vrule height 0pt depth 10cm}%
}

\subsection*{Bad}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](3)
\task Gaussian process machine learning 
\task Statistical learning theory  
\task (Non)-convex optimization
%
\task (Non)-convex optimization
\task Statistical learning theory  
\task Gaussian process machine learning 
\end{tasks}

\subsection*{Better}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize,item-format=\raggedright](3)
\task Gaussian process machine learning 
\task Statistical learning theory  
\task (Non)-convex optimization
%
\task (Non)-convex optimization
\task Statistical learning theory  
\task Gaussian process machine learning 
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

You may want to add `item-format=\raggedright` to the `\settasks` initialization.

[image]